# Unzip ZIP file and extract unknown folder name's content

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

My users will be zipping up files which will look like this:

```
TEMPLATE1.ZIP
   |--------- UnknownName
                   |------- index.html
                   |------- images
                               |------- image1.jpg
```

I want to extract this zip file as follows:

```
/mysite/user_uploaded_templates/myrandomname/index.html
/mysite/user_uploaded_templates/myrandomname/images/image1.jpg
```

My trouble is with UnknownName - I do not know what it is beforehand and extracting everything to the "base" level breaks all the relative paths in index.html

How can I extract from this ZIP file the **contents** of UnknownName?

Is there *anything* better than:

```
1. Extract everything
2. Detect which "new subdidrectory" got created
3. mv newsubdir/* .
4. rmdir newsubdir/
```

If there is more than one subdirectory at UnknownName level, I can reject that user's zip file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your approach is a good one. Step 2 could be improved my extracting to a newly created directory (later deleted) so that "detection" is trivial.

```
# Bash (minimally tested)
tempdest=$(mktemp -d)
unzip -d "$tempdest" TEMPLATE1.ZIP
dir=("$tempdest"/*)
if (( ${#dir[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -d $dir ]]
    # in Bash, etc., scalar $var is the same as ${var[0]}
    mv "$dir"/* /mysite/user_uploaded_templates/myrandomname
else
    echo "rejected"
fi
rm -rf "$tempdest"
```

Comment: looking for `dir=("$tempdest"/*)`

Answer (score 0):

The other option I can see other than the one you suggested is to use the `unzip -j` flag which will dump all paths and put all files into the current directory.  If you know for certain that each of your `TEMPLATE1.ZIP` files includes an `index.html` and `*.jpg` files then you can just do something like:

```
destdir=/mysite/user_uploaded_templates/myrandomname
unzip -j -d "$destdir"
mkdir "${destdir}/images"
mv "${destdir}/*.jpg" "${destdir}/images"
```

It's not exactly the cleanest solution but at least you don't have to do any parsing like you do in your example.  I can't seem to find any option similar to `patch -p#` that lets you specify the path level.

Answer (score 0):

Each `zip` and `unzip` command differs, but there's usually a way to list the file contents. From there, you can parse the output to determine the unknown directory name.

On Windows, the 1996 Wales/Gaily/van der Linden/Rommel version it is `unzip -l`.

Of course, you could just simply allow the unzip to unzip the files to whatever directory it wants, then use `mv` to rename the directory to what you want it as.

```
$tempDir = temp.$$
mv $zipFile temp.$$
cd $tempDir
unzip $zipFile
$unknownDir = *   #Should be the only directory here
mv $unknownDir $whereItShouldBe
cd ..
rm -rf $tempDir
```

It's always a good idea to create a temporary directory for these types of operations in case you end up running two instances of this command.